# How to get File name from uploaded path in php

Tags: php

I uploaded the file and stored the path in the database table. when i trying to retrieve the file name it displays the full path of the particular uploaded file.

for example:
**stored path in table :** wp-content/uploads/images/adminupload/dummy-pdf_2.pdf

**expected result :** dummy-pdf_2.pdf

please anyone tell me how to get the file name from uploaded path. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use basename function

$path = "wp-content/uploads/images/adminupload/dummy-pdf_2.pdf";

$filename = basename($path);